# How to log values of @Input/@Output values by custom decorator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, decorator

I am trying to log every value that is incoming (input) and outgoing (output) of my component by simply providing/using a custom decorator. I just don't get to the point where I could possibly read/print some values.

**Custom Decorator**

```
function Log() {
  return (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    console.log('this: ', this) // this: undefined
    console.log('target: ', target) // target: Object { constructor: f FooComponent() }
    console.log('propertyKey: ', propertyKey) // propertyKey: source
    console.log('descriptor: ', descriptor) // descriptor: undefined
    return descriptor;
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
export class FooComponent  {
  // This observable just emits 'one', 'two' and 'three' one by one.
  public source$ = of(['one', 'two', 'three']).pipe(
    mergeMap(identity)
  )

  // Wanted usage (if possible)
  @Output() @Log() source = this.source$;
}
```

**Expected output in the console**

```
one
two
three
```

The `@Output()` decorator still works and I get values emitted from `FooComponent`. But I have no clue how to read out the variable that is going through this decorator, or even read the values from it. I already tried the following body of `Log`:

- `this[propertyKey]` (here I receive an error for not being able to read a property of undefined)
- `target[propertyKey]` (here I just receive undefined)

In case you need a test-setup: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-output-log-decorator)

Comment: Look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). Especially in the section where it starts to refer to [`reflect-metadata`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata); the lower half of the page..

Comment: With rxjs there are better alternative to intercept observables, decorator doesn't seem to be very appropriate to be in use here.

Comment: @FanCheung I am using alternative ways to log values. In pipes using tap. Decorators for getter/setter. Decorator for functions. This question is really just about decorators for Input / Output. For me it would be also ok, if it's technically not possible.

Comment: I think it is technically possible, but implementation can be so tricky, take a look here https://dev.to/angular/decorators-do-not-work-as-you-might-expect-3gmj
Since your instance property is an observable, that will require you to .pipe another logger to intercept the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @FanCheung, whose article reference gave me the right knowledge to build the decorator.

**Log decorator**

```
function Log(): any {
  return (target, propertyKey, propertyDescriptor) => {
    const key = Symbol();
    return {
      get() {
        return this[key]; 
      },
      set(newValue: Observable<any>) {
        console.log(newValue);
        this[key] = newValue.pipe(
          tap(v => console.error(`${String(propertyKey)}: `, v))
        );
        if (propertyDescriptor) {
          propertyDescriptor.set(newValue);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
// Class with decorator usage
class Foo {
  private readonly source$ = of('baz');
  @Output() @Log() source = this.source$
}

// Usage of Foo as <foo>
<foo (source)="..."></foo>

// Expected output
source: baz
```

**Explanation**

Deep insights about what is actually happening can be found in the article [Decorators do not work as you might expect](https://dev.to/angular/decorators-do-not-work-as-you-might-expect-3gmj).